# How to install Semantic ui for Next.js

Tags: next.js, semantic-ui

[image]

I have one problem here and cant solve it. I want to install Semantic ui on Next.js application via npm but it's impossible please help me.

if u have some ideas please help me

```
npm install semantic-ui
```

I tried this one but nothing changes.

Comment: What output do you get from npm?

Comment: while Im tryng to import semantic on the top of my file I get this one (ill uplod photo in post)

Comment: Could you put the error from the image into your question? Text in images is not searchable and reduces the chance that someone can help answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I use semantic-ui-react in my next.js project and I like to use my own theme. Follow the instructions below to get going.

First and foremost run `npm install --save-dev semantic-ui`. Soon you will see an interactive prompt. Answer questions presented the following way.

1. Set-up Semantic UI - **Choose ‘Express (Set components and output folder)’**
2. We detected you are using NPM Nice! Is this your project folder? - **Choose ‘Yes’**
3. Where should we put Semantic UI inside your project? **Hit return (This will put a directory named ‘semantic’ in root)**
4. What components should we include in the package? **This is upto you. Check the ones you need and uncheck the ones you don’t.**
5. Should we set permissions on outputted files? **Choose ‘No’**
6. Do you use a RTL (Right-To-Left) language? **Pick your favourite option**
7. 7. Where should we output Semantic UI? **Write a custom path in your terminal** `../static/semantic/dist`

Now we are going to need gulp to run compilation tasks to build your theme.css under dist/ directory that you will use in your project.

Run `yarn add --dev gulp`

and add the following to your package.json under “scripts” like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build-semantic": "cd semantic && gulp build-css build-assets”,
    "watch-semantic": "cd semantic && yarn run build-semantic && gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "semantic-ui": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Now if you run `yarn watch-semantic`, gulp will compile source files and create a `dist/` under `semantic/`.  Under dist/ you will see semantic.min.css
We are just about done. Now you have to include this .css in page/component that is shared by all pages or components. Fortunately, next.js has a solution.

_document.js (https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-document)

Create _document.js under pages/ and include your recently created semantic.min.css like below.

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="/static/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body className="custom_class">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the following in _app.js:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
```

You will need: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css.

Then, you can follow the advice I found here: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/432.
Specifically, see antonioOrtiz 24 Mar comment.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice starter project that uses Next.js + Fomantic-UI + Styled Components.

https://github.com/skydiver/nextjs-semantic

For Semantic-UI version, check out `v1.1.0` branch.

https://github.com/skydiver/nextjs-semantic/tree/v1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative I haven't seen mentioned in the comments yet:
Create a layout wrapper around your pages and import there the library CSS from the CDN.

```js
import Head from 'next/head';

const Layout = () => (
    <>
        <Head>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </Head>
        {children}
    </>
);

export default Layout;
```

And in your pages:

```js
import Layout from '@components/Layout';

const AboutPage = () => (
        <Layout>
            <article>
               I am the about page
            </article>
        </Layout>  
);

export default AboutPage;
```

It will allows to do some quick tests without having to install any additional packages.